# Scala GADT Fantom Type interpreter error: found Any Required A

Tags: scala

I have a fairly trivial algebra.

```
sealed abstract class Kvp[A]
case class KvpString(key: String) extends Kvp[String]
case class KvpInt(key: String) extends Kvp[Int]
case class KvpBool(key: String) extends Kvp[Boolean]
case class KvpPair[A,B](p1: Kvp[A], p2: Kvp[B]) extends Kvp[(A,B)]
```

And I'm trying to create an interpreter which returns a function from Json => A.  However, I am having to type cast back to A for the code to compile.

```
  import argonaut._, Argonaut._

  def eval[A](kvp: Kvp[A]) : Json => A = {
    val result = kvp match {
      case KvpString(key) =>
        (json: Json) =>
          json.field(key).flatMap(_.string).get
      case KvpInt(key) =>
        (json: Json) =>
          json.field(key).flatMap(_.number).flatMap(_.toInt).get
      case KvpBool(key) =>
        (json: Json) =>
          json.field(key).flatMap(_.bool).get
      case KvpPair(p1, p2) =>
        (json: Json) =>
          (eval(p1).apply(json), eval(p2).apply(json))
    }
    result // <-- this would result in the error
    result.asInstanceOf[Json => A] // so I have to do this
 }
```

If `result` is the last statement, at compile I will get this error.

```
[error]  found   : argonaut.Json => Any
[error]  required: argonaut.Json => A
[error]     result
```

This syntax code style seems pretty standard in the Cats examples, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Haven't you forget to restrict the type parameters of `KvpPair` to only be `Kvp`s? This way the last conversion is quite unsafe.

Comment: @GáborBakos The two parameters are (p1: Kvp[A], p2: Kvp[B]), so they are required to be Kvp.  However, I think this may be a more appropriate way to encode it: case class KvpPair[A1, K1<:Kvp[A1], A2, K2<:Kvp[A2]](k1: K1, k2: K2) extends Kvp[(A1,A2)] I made this update and am still getting the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the Scala compiler is not smart enough to auto-infer the type `Json => A` from the code of your `match`/`case`: all the return types in different branches are different so type `Json => Any` is inferred. But it is smart enough to typecheck against such a type if it has to. So try to specify the type explicitly at the declaration of the `result` as in:

```
  val result: (Json => A) = kvp match {
```

alternatively remove the `result` variable whatsoever and just return the whole `kvp match` statement, then the compiler will try to typecheck against the expected return type of the method and it should work as well.

Comment: Note that this does work with thte scala compiler, however Intellij (ver 2018.1) will show an error for each Lamda bodies, such as "Int Doesn't Conform to Type A"